# How to see (or check) values of macro function in C during debugging mode in MS visual studio?

Tags: c, visual-studio

I would like to check a numerical value evaluated by a function macro in C during debugging mode. I defined a function as macro like below.

```
#define H_H2(T)        0.2584e4*exp(170/(T))
```

When I tried to evaluate this function  `H_H2(298)` during debugging mode at watch window in Visual studio, it generated an error `identifier "H_H2" is undefined`.

Could someone let me know how to evaluate a macro function during debugging mode ?

Comment: You don't. From [Expressions in the Visual Studio debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/expressions-in-the-debugger?view=vs-2019#preprocessor-macros): "*Preprocessor macros are not supported in the debugger. [...] To avoid this limitation, you should replace #define's with enums and functions ...*".

Comment: Your only option is to step through the disassembled view of the code.

Comment: I'm not a huge fan of debugging through decompiled code.  For a project of any reasonable size, this can be quite difficult.

Answer (score 3):

You can't.  Macros are resolved during the preprocessor, and as a result they don't exist in compiled code.

If you need to debug such an expression, create a function, or step through the disassembled code (Ctrl+,G in VS2019).

Comment: It is not exactly the true. Gcc and -g3 plus eclipse are allowing us to see how the macros are expanded and evaluated. Step by step

Comment: I forgot to add it not possible in vs

Comment: True - some environments are richer than others and may be aware enough to add extra debugging info to a bianary.  Pedantically speaking, though, macros don't exist after pre-processing, so the compiler can't really know about them to emit debug symbols.

Comment: `-g3 "includes extra information such as macro definitions... Some debuggers support macro expansion when you use -g3", while -g does not include this extra information.` gdb supports it. VS does not support gdb. Compiler may parse original source as many times as it wants. It is probably additional pass

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible in the VisualStudio if you use Microsft debugger. But you can debug it if you use `gdb` and `gcc` compiler. It is possible if you debug WSL application in the VS https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/linux/deploy-run-and-debug-your-linux-project?view=msvc-160.

When you compiler using gcc family debuggers and use gdb you can easily see and evaluate macro definitions by adding the `-g3` compiler option.

From `gcc` documentation:

> Level 3 includes extra information, such as all the macro definitions
> present in the program. Some debuggers support macro expansion when
> you use -g3.